# No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I'm fully aware that this question has been asked many times before, but none of the solutions seem to be working for me. Everything was running perfectly well, and then after reloading my app firebase just seemed to shut down. I tried re-running my app and retyping firebase-related sections of my code numerous times, but nothing has worked to fix this issue. I would really appreciate any help or guidance you can provide towards helping me with this fix.

### Here's where I initialize my firebase

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import Requests from './Requests'
import {
    Provider
} from 'react-redux'
import {
    createStore,
    applyMiddleware
} from 'redux'
import reducers from '../reducers/EventReducer'
import Thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const store = createStore(reducers,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    applyMiddleware(Thunk))

class App extends React.Component {
        componentWillMount = () => {
            firebase.initializeApp({
                apiKey: "my key",
                authDomain: "my domain",
                databaseURL: "my url",
                projectId: "my id",
                storageBucket: "my storage bucket",
                messagingSenderId: "my messagingSenderID"
            })
        }
```

Comment: try by calling it from `constructor()`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried that, and it still doesn't seem to be working :(